# How to display window just one time in java Timer

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Timer in my app. Timer connects and disconnects database every 10 sec. This is just to know when my db is unreacheble. Maybe there are other ways. But I did so.
How to display the alert window once to successfully connect and bring back with repeated tripping?
Thanks any help!

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    SqlTransport.openConnectionToDB();
                    System.out.println("connect");
                    if (SqlTransport.openConnectionToDB() == false) {
                        alertWindow.display();
                        caseCount.setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("noConnection");
                    }else {
                    System.out.println("connectDone");
                    caseCount.setVisible(true);
                        caseCount.setText(String.valueOf(SqlTransport.getOpenedCount()));
                        pause.playFromStart();
                        pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
                            SqlTransport.closeConnectionToDB();
                            System.out.println("closeDone");
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 10000, 10000);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve if the connection is successful? Pausing the timer and waiting for a response on the dialog? And what are you expecting after the dialog has shown?

Comment: What timer do: connect to db. It gets some value there. Display in Label an then close connection. Pause between connect and because it very fast close connection and sometimes my another method does not work because of lack of connection. I need to see the dialogue once for all time, check the connection until a successful connection to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean field to your `TimerTask` which indicates if the connection worked last time it was checked. Set the field appropriately every time the task runs. Only display the window if there was a connection last time.

EDIT: here's some code, try it out.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    // It's possible that a starting value of false will
    // match your desired behaviour better.
    // Experiment with a situation where there is no connection initially.
    boolean previouslyConnected = true;

    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SqlTransport.openConnectionToDB();
                System.out.println("connect");
                boolean connected = SqlTransport.openConnectionToDB();
                // ! means 'not'. This is typically written instead of 'connected == false'
                if (!connected) {
                    if (previouslyConnected) {
                        alertWindow.display();
                    }
                    caseCount.setVisible(false);
                    System.out.println("noConnection");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("connectDone");
                    caseCount.setVisible(true);
                    caseCount.setText(String.valueOf(SqlTransport.getOpenedCount()));
                    pause.playFromStart();
                    pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
                        SqlTransport.closeConnectionToDB();
                        System.out.println("closeDone");
                    });
                }
                previouslyConnected = connected;
            }
        });
    }
}, 10000, 10000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not really understand how to do it

Comment: Thank you! But I get the alertWindow every 10 seconds.

Comment: I can't see why that would be the case and it's not easy for me to run the code and debug. Can you run the code through a debugger? Do you understand what I've done?

Comment: It seems so. We say that the previous connection was successful. Then memorize the current connection status. If there is no connection, and vproshly once was, the output dialog. And assigns the connection to the past state of the false to no longer call the dialog. I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Have you tried using a debugger? It's very easy from an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ. If you've never tried such tools it's well worth it for many other reasons.

Comment: It seems it's not reached previously Connected = connected;
I register in if and else separately, all perfectly working. And I thought that it was wrong and ordered previouslyConnected = connected; initially.
Corrected how you as an example. Everything works great! Thank you so much!